# Quick terminology question - "Standardizing" Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

This is a really boring question I apologize. I'm not sure what to call this process, I call it "standardization" however perhaps non beginners would think I'm being sloppy with terminology. For example

- if $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $(X - \mu)/\sigma \sim N(0,1)$
- if $X \sim Expo(\lambda)$ then $\lambda X \sim Expo(1)$
- if $X \sim Gamma(n,\lambda)$ then $\lambda X \sim Gamma(n,1)$
- if $X \sim U(a,b)$ then $\frac{X-a}{b-a} \sim U(0,1)$

RV's where this doesn't work or make sense:

- Poisson, Hypergeometric, Binomial, Chi Squared, Bernoulli, Geometric, Negative Binomial, Beta

**My question:** Would this be called "standardization" or should that be reserved exclusively for normal RVs? Or should "standardization" be reserved exclusively for the RV $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ with mean $0$ and var $1$ which doesn't make as much sense for something like the Exponential? What would you call this process?

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: There's also the standard Cauchy, standard Weilbull, standard Fisher–Tippett distribution etc. It's about [shifting and scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family) so "naturally" not all distributions apply.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Interesting I didn't know those other distributions could be shifted and scaled (I haven't studied them as much). I suppose I could say "shift and scale to a standard Cauchy" versus "standardized Cauchy"... if I say "standard Expo" then I think most people would infer an Expo with rate 1